# Why define Parent class as friend class?

Tags: c++

I am looking at other's code and find one part I can't understand.

```
class a {
   public:
   function xxx () {.....}
}

class b : public a {
   public:
       xxxx
   protected:
       constructor()....

       friend class a ;            <=  here why it is needed ????

}
```

As I understand, since b had already inherited from a, it should be able to use the function of a directly. What's the purpose of this "friend" declaration used for?

Comment: It means an instance of `a` can call `b::constructor()` and other non-public memberd of `b`. It has nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`friend class a;` grants class `a` the right to access non-public members of `b`. So in this small example, an instance of `a` can call `b::constructor()`. Without friendship, it wouldn't be possible.

As to why, there is not enough information to answer that, other than there must be a need for instances of `a` to call `b::constructor()` (assuming that to be anything other than the syntax error it currently is).

Comment: Thanks. I figured out I understanded the "friend class" in wrong directions. Indeed, class b is a abstract class that only permit specified class to call it's constructor. I'll tick this answer . thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The `friend` allows `a` to use `b`'s methods, not the other way around, which isn't implicit.

The design looks fishy though, a base class shouldn't care about derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand, since b had already inherited from a, it should be able to use the function of a directly.

Yes. The friend specification though allows access the other way around (instances of `a` will be able to access private data and functions of `b`).

> What's the purpose of this "friend" declaration used for?

The example above doesn't suggest any. The only situation where it may make sense is with using CRTP in certain situations (i.e. a is `a` template of `b`) but even so, if you see such a requirement ("must add friend declaration in b") it is possible that the design you're looking at is flawed.

Can you post a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your projects/requirements, your class designs change. I have no comment on your class hierarchy but true your question is all about theories of friend usage.  If you don't use friend, you will not be able to call B members from A. It is there for...cross-mating :D

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly means that there is a serious design problem. One of the basic rules of thumb for inheritance is that base classes should not need any information about derived classes. Making `a` a friend of `b` makes it possible for member functions of `a` to get at the internals of `b` objects.